# sending string in android bluetooth

Tags: java, android, import, bluetooth

I have my major project on **android based home automation system** meaning that I have to control home appliances using android bluetooth. I am using HC-05 bluetooth module which receives the string sent to it through my application, sends it to PIC16f877a and the pic in turn depending upon the string received, controls the appliances. Now my problem is that I have been able to pair and connect the devices through my application but my application is not sending the characters which I want to send when I click the button. Note that PIC and the Bluetooth module are working fine. please help me. I am posting my code below hope you guys won't mind.

```
package com.chainedcat.splashscreen;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivityActivity extends Activity{

private BluetoothAdapter BA;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
private ListView lv;
private TextView text;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket=null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34EB");
private OutputStream outStream=null;

public void Init(){
    BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    text =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    btArrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1); 
    lv.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    Init();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
           if(selectedDevice.getBondState()== BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE){
                 pairDevice(selectedDevice);
            }
           else if(selectedDevice.getBondState()==BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                connect(selectedDevice);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void bluetooth(View view){
    if(!BA.isEnabled()){
    Intent btIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(btIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth turned on!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        btExtra();
    }else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is already on!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    btExtra();
    }

}

public void btExtra(){

    btArrayAdapter.clear();
    BA.startDiscovery();
    registerReceiver(btReceiver, new tentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    }

final BroadcastReceiver btReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            devices.add(device);
            String status=null;
            if(device.getBondState()==BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                status="paired";
            }else{status="not paired";}
            btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+" : "+status+"\n"+device.getAddress());
            btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if(BA.isEnabled()){
            text.setText("Bluetooth Status:Enabled");
        }else{
            text.setText("Bluetooth Status:Disabled");
        }           
    }
}

private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
     Method m=null;
    try {
        m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     connect(device);
}

public void connect(BluetoothDevice device){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connecting....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        btSocket=device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BA.cancelDiscovery();
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "entered in run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        btSocket.connect();
        if(btSocket!=null){btSocket.close();}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void send(String s){
    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    try {
        outStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void fan(View v){
    send("f");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    BA.disable();
    unregisterReceiver(btReceiver);
}
}
```

Comment: ok now I have found that the bluetooth device was not connected to my android phone at all but I don't know why. please help!!!!!!